# Hints on an expository article about Kardar-Parisi-Zhang (KPZ)

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics

It seems the KPZ is the next big thing in mathematical physics and probability. The skeletal idea is probably that while classical averages are in the Gaussian universality class, lots of other statistics seem to converge to the KPZ.

I was thinking of writing an expository article in a magazine on the KPZ to spread awareness and enrich my knowledge. I would like the article to be not too technical; I would definitely avoid proofs, but I would want to present the main results and the synthesis among them. I would like to focus more on the philosophy of these results rather than the exact computations.

I am not sure if this is too premature to be presented as an exposition. I am looking for articles that describe the KPZ, although I did not really find many, apart from Quastel and Corwin's notes.

What really is the KPZ all about and why are people interested in it? If you have references to articles that are involved in the development of KPZ, without probably realizing (often much of the realizations come later), feel free to point them out.  What would be a good systematic approach to the subject?

Comment: I think you should read https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.03044 to first see how KPZ fits in a much larger picture about understanding non-Gaussian scaling limits and their universality properties.

Comment: I thought the introduction of Corwin's paper (assuming you mean this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1596 ) did a great job of explaining what KPZ is and why people care about it. Is there something more specific that you feel is missing in the extant surveys of the theory?

Comment: you might also like this [introduction](https://academic.oup.com/ptep/article-pdf/2016/2/022A01/9620675/ptw002.pdf) to the 1D case.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks for the reference, I would like these articles first, instead of Corwin's which is somewhat technical. I am as of now trying to understand the science behind the KPZ.

Comment: @andrewRichards Here are two other recent survey articles: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.01910.pdf https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.06185.pdf